# Python and curl equivalent

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have an old `curl` (not mine) and I can't figure out how to convert it to use python requests.

Can someone help me?

Here the `curl`:

```
        $ch = curl_init($url);      //Initiate cURL.
        $jsonData = array(      //The JSON data.
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $password
        );
        $jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);  //Encode the array into JSON.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);      //Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded); //Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'/*, 'Connection: keep-alive'*/)); //Set the content type to application/json
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true); //Execute the request
```

Comment: If only there were [online resources](https://curl.trillworks.com/) that could [help with this sort of request](https://reqbin.com/req/python/c-xgafmluu/convert-curl-to-python-requests).

Comment: Ah ah ah ah ah..... Do you think you are nice?  Do you think I haven't tried and tried?  It did not work. Suddenly worked

Comment: If you've tried something and it didn't work, you need to provide those details in your question. If you do that, we can help you spot the problem and correct it. If you just say "it isn't working" and don't provide any additional details, it looks like you haven't tried anything. Keep in mind that everyone here is a volunteer, and while we're happy to help out, we're generally not willing to write code for you or otherwise act as replacement for google/documentation/tutorials. I'm sorry if that comment made you unhappy; I hope that it will also help you write better questions in the future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved

```
mydata = {'email': form.vars.email, 'password':form.vars.password}
resp= requests.post('url', json = mydata)
```

I don't know why but I had already tried it and it didn't work